# Выбор номера вместо константы

Tags: c

Существует программа (игрушка) - разгадать номер, сам загаданный номер хранится в константе HOT, возможно ли сделать выборку загаданного номера? К примеру, я (создатель) зашел в программу, ввел какой-нибудь ключ, или еще что-нибудь и теперь могу вписать другой номер, далее просто программа начинает работать с тем номером, реально ли такое?

```
/* 
 * Copyright ©
 * Author: Valentin
 * Date: November 2012
 * Version: 1.0
 * Programa 13: Mini jogo, acertar o numero
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#define HOT 69

main()
{
    system("color 2");
    int nr, cont = -1;

    do {
    printf("Insira o numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &nr);
    cont++;
    while (nr < 0 || nr > 100) {
        printf("\nO numero inserido e invalido. O mesmo deve estar compreendido entre 0 e 100.\n\n");
        cont++;
        printf("Insira o numero: ");
        scanf("%i", &nr);
    }
    if (nr < (HOT - 5)) {
        printf("O numero introduzido esta muito baixo.\n");
    }
    if (nr > (HOT + 5)) {
        printf("O numero introduzido esta muito alto.\n");
    }
    if (nr <= (HOT + 5) && nr > HOT) {
        printf("O numero introduzido esta alto, mas perto.\n");
    }
    if (nr >= (HOT - 5) && nr < HOT) {
        printf("O numero introduzido esta baixo, mas perto.\n");
    }
    } while (nr != HOT);

    printf("\nParabens, ganhou! O numero era: %i.\n", HOT);
    printf("Voce falhou %i vezes.\n", cont);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: о_О это что, испанский, португальский? Начинаю понимать свое недопонимание :)

Comment: Abordagem exclusivamente Português para a resolução de problemas.

Comment: Португальский.

Comment: Можно число хранить во внешнем файле в зашифрованном виде.

Comment: @extazys, а в чем проблема? Может я что-то принципиально не понимаю, но IMHO все решается заменой строчки

    #define HOT 69

на

    static int HOT = 69;

Потом можно вытащить смещение HOT из таблицы символов и модифицировать исполняемый модуль.

--

Но, для начала протестируйте свою программу, например введите букву вместо числа...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вопрос как поменять загаданное число, так все просто. Нужно просто поменять строчку

```
#define HOT 69
```

Вместо 69 подставить свое любое число.

Если хочется, чтобы программа сама произвольно загадывала число, то тоже нет проблем. Тогда достаточно вставить вызов ф-ции [rand()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/), предварительно инициализировав ГСЧ каким-либо значением.

Answer (score 0):

Удаляешь строчку:

```
#define HOT 69
```

Пподключаешь библиотеку stdlib:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

а в начало функции main() пишешь:

```
main()
{
   srand(time(0));
   int HOT = rand()%99+1;//От 1 до 100.
   ...
}
```

Программа будет случайно при каждом запуске генерировать число.

Comment: А в линуксе (думаю в других \*nix-ах тоже) нет `randomize()`. Лучше использовать стандартный `rand()`.

Comment: @avp

     /dev/random, /dev/urandom

Comment: Не знал...
Но стандартный, то есть просто rand() будет постоянно выдавать одно и то же число.
А если 
подключить ещё time.h
и использовать srand(time(0)) ?

Comment: Естественно.